# Unpack gma files

Tags: add-on, unpack, garrys-mod

When I move the addon for the Garry's mod with the gma extension to gmad.exe, the command line flickers for a second and nothing else happens, the files are not unpacked, can anyone know why?

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on topic in the [help/on-topic].